# Plotly + iPython Notebook - Plots Disappear on Reopen

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, plotly

When I create a notebook with plotly plots, save and reopen the notebook, the plots fail to render upon reopening - there are just blank blocks where the plots should be. Is this expected behavior? If not, is there a known fix?

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure your notebook is marked as "trusted", either in the top-right corner of the notebook, or in the *File* menu.

My notebooks are trusted by default, but I managed to reproduce your observed behaviour by temporarily removing my `~/Library/Jupyter/nbsignatures.db` file, which forces Jupyter to run the notebook as untrusted. Clicking the tile in the top-right corner to trust the notebook fixed the issue for me.

This page in the jupyter docs, [Security in notebook documents](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#notebook-security) explains further:

> The security problem we need to solve is that no code should execute just because a user has opened a notebook that they did not write. Like any other program, once a user decides to execute code in a notebook, it is considered trusted, and should be allowed to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this annoying issue. I find no way to reveal them on the notebook, but I find a compromise way to display them on an html page that is **File -> Print Preview**.

Answer (score 0):

The reason as documented [here](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/):

> Note: Default renderers persist for the duration of a single session,
> but they do not persist across sessions. If you are working in an
> IPython kernel, this means that default renderers will persist for the
> life of the kernel, but they will not persist across kernel restarts.

As indicated in the [troubleshooting documentation](https://plotly.com/python/troubleshooting/#jupyter-notebook-classic-problems), "JupyterLab Problems" section, You have two options to solve the problem:

1. calling `fig.show("notebook")` instead of just `fig.show()`.
2. If this problem is recurrent, you can use this:

> ```
> import plotly.io as pio
> pio.renderers.default='notebook'
> ```

Credits for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60654984/16733101)